# createPopUpMenu in wxWIdgets sometimes displays menu away from taskbar

Tags: c++, popup, wxwidgets

I am using `wxTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu` to display menu for my application. Sometimes it takes 2-3 seconds for menu to display because of certain checks. If we right click on taskbar icon of application and then move the mouse to some other place on screen then PopUp menu is displayed near current mouse position. I want that PopUp menu should be displayed near taskbar icon of that application even if current mouse position is somewhere else. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: maybe you should start using thread if the delay is so significant?

Comment: arent you showing PopupMenu using `event.PopupMenu`? If the event is generated on the taskbar then it should be shown on the taskbar

Comment: @macroland no, I am using wxTaskBarIcon::CreatePopupMenu() from here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_task_bar_icon.html#a739c81dc5cadf9e550d38001cee419f6